# Using SSIS to connect to server with 2 Factor Authentication

Tags: sql-server, ssis, google-authenticator

I have a SQL Server instance running on RDS, with some source data located in a server elsewhere.

The source server is only accessible using 2FA (Google Authenticator). Can anyone please steer me in the direction of how I can connect automatically to download the data once a day?

Thanks

M

Comment: what format source data look like ? is it from MS sql tables or files ?

Comment: The data is on a mysql server, however in order to access the server you need 2FA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example (Connect to Google analytics using SSIS package)
https://jeeveshfuloria08.wordpress.com/2013/08/30/access-google-analytics-api-3-0-using-oauth2-0-in-ssis/